# Encountering some issues when installing Android studio hedgehog

Tags: android-studio

i am trying to upgrage my android studio Eel to Android studio hedgehog on my mac and i got this error dialog when trying to launch my android studio :

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
```

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.java:761)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:854)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1068)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:397)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: getEventDispatchThread() must not be null
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$startApplication$appDeferred$1$rwLockHolderDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:231)
... 6 more

How could i solve it ?